# Numbering dynamic table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on making a dynamic HTML table using jQuery. In a table, my user has two interactions:

1. Append a row
2. Remove a specific row

The problem with numbering the rows is that if a user removes a specific row, all of the rows following that row need to be renumbered. I would have to select all rows following the removed row and subtract their number by 1.

Is there a better way to go about this?

EDIT: Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/LNXae/2/

I'm aware that an ordered-list would automatically renumber my rows, but I'd rather use a table since the example I'm giving now is pretty boiled-down.

Comment: Can you let us know why you need to do this? If you are repairing broken foreign keys, your normalisation probably needs fixing. Don't forget also that a foreign key and a display code can be separate columns - and that once created, primary/foreign keys should have no reason to change.

Comment: @halfer, I believe he wants to change the text on a html page - because of the `jQuery` tag.

Comment: Ah, thanks @Moo-Juice - I thought it was referring to a database `:)`

Comment: Have you considered using an ordered list instead?

Comment: @Blazemonger I would be using a list, but I need to have columns for other things in the table, and I don't want to worry about nested divs..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/LNXae/1/

First, wrap the counter number in a `<span>` with a class for easy finding later:

```
$new_row.children('td').prepend('Row #<span class="num">' + ($new_row.index() + 1) + "</span>");
```

Then update all these spans with an `.each` loop after you remove the desired row. The first argument passed into `.each`'s callback function is a zero-based index number, and the second is the HTML element:

```
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        $table = $row.closest('table');
    $row.remove();

    $table.find('tr').each(function(i, v) {
        $(v).find('span.num').text(i + 1);
    });
```

Comment: That's actually really clever! The fix that I came up with in JSFiddle isn't anywhere near as concise, but it only loops through the siblings that come after the deleted row : http://jsfiddle.net/LNXae/2/

Is there not a better way to do this? It seems very inefficient.

Comment: If the number of table rows is relatively small (as in, less than a thousand), any such optimizations will be unnoticeable to the user.

Answer (score 1):

After the user has appended a row, or deleted one, you just need to iterate over the "number" cells.  If we assume that you have a `<td>` element, we:

1) give them a nice ID, e.g. `row_0`, `row_1`, etc...

2) write a function to iterate over them:

```
function updateRows(){
    $('[id*="row_"]').each(function(index){
        $(this).html(index + 1); // add +1 to prevent 0 index.
    };
};
```

Answer (score -2):

I have written a jquery plugin which does exactly this, and you shouldnt need to "number" the rows per-se. All you need to do when deleting a row is to pass the *index* of the row being deleted.

eg, if you have a delete button in a row:

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td> <input type="button" class="delete" value="delete this row" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The jQuery might look like

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
 var index = $(this).parents('tr').index();
 // tell your plugin to delete row "index"
});
```

The method from *my* plugin which does this looks something like:

```
removeRow: function (index) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var $tbody = $('tbody', $this);
            var $tr = $('tr', $tbody).eq(index);
            $this.trigger('rowRemoved', [$tr]);
            $tr.remove();
        });
    }
```

Comment: I think (as the post could be a bit ambiguous), he has cells that are numbered '001', '002', '003'... etc, and that they are incorrect after deleting or adding.